# Intent deeplink always opens play store after adding Referr to package

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, deep-linking

I have two types of deeplinks. An install deeplink that should try to open the application if installed and then fallback to opening the play store if the app is not installed. The second deeplink; however, tries to open the app if it is installed, otherwise it opens a web page as a fallback.

The problem is that when I add a referrer parameter to the package, it starts opening the play store even if the application is installed.

**Install deeplink:**

`Intent://mypath/?cc=de&tagset=2#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=com.mypackage&referrer=myreferrer;`

**Opening deeplink:**

`Intent://mypath/?cc=de&tagset=2#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=com.mypackage;S.browser_fallback_url=my_fallback_web_url;`

Answer (score 0):

Android will use everything that is between `package:` and `;` to determine the packagename of the app to launch/install.

In your example, the package will be `com.mypackage&referrer=myreferrer` which is different from `com.mypackage`.

You could instead use `S.referrer=myreferrer;` instead and parse it in your app.

Comment: The S.referrer parameter does not exist or can you please refer me to how you figured this out ? I used this parameter and still, the browser does not pass the data in S.referrer to the play store.
So far, the only way to pass the referrer is to add &referrer=myreferrer to the package, and this is exactly what causes the behavior of opening the play store app even if the app is installed.

Comment: I don't think the playstore handles the referrer when launched with Chrome Android Intent. You can try to put it after the `mypath/?cc&referrer=myreferrer`. The `S.referrer` parameter will be provided to your app as a Bundle parameter. You can use `S.whatever` for any value.

Comment: I have tested this approach and the results show that this is wrong. The browser will not just pass every parameter to the Play store and on the other side, the play store will not just pass any param to the App once it's installed.

Comment: No, the `S.parameter` will be passed when your app is directly opened. Maybe checkout new Firebase deeplinks ;)

Comment: I have added few S.params and checked what is passed from the play app to my app(I use Alpha version to actually download my test app from the store after passing those parameters and I open the app from the store button) and those S.params don't show up on the application side. Would you please provide a link to docs for this. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: They are only forwarded when app is already installed. You could try to use the fallback url as the playstore url with the referrer inside.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use an undocumented extra parameter `S.market_referrer=`.

[Source](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459711&thanks=459711&ts=1424288965)